# E-SQL in Entity Framework DbContext

Tags: code-first, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I'm using EF 5.0 Code First API, and I need to add the ability for building dynamic OrderBy expressions (the UI has a filter panel where users can choose multiple oredering criteria (e. g. select top 20 Customers, order by LastName ASC, then by Birst Date DESC).

ObjectContext API exposes `OrderBy("it.PropertyName")` method which looks great, despite it's missing compile time verification. However, I can't find any analogues in the DbContext API.

Googling the problem I found such advice:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)myContextInstance).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<MyEntity>("<ESQL Query>")
```

However, I would not like to give up LINQ query at all.
Are there any ways to have something like this (mix ESQL and LINQ, as it could be by using ObjectContext):

```
var customers = myDbContext.Customers.OrderBy("it.LastName desc").Where(c => c.Age < 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?  I'm not sure about mixing ESQL and LINQ, but your last query can be done entirely from LINQ.

`var customers = myDbContext.Customers.OrderByDescending(a => a.LastName).ThenBy(c => c.BirthDate).Where(b => b.Age < 18);`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the point is, that conditions could be added dynamically and I don't know beforehand what columns will be used in filtering. For now, I'm using dynamic LINQ.